# I'm having difficulty using Latex preview in org mode

Tags: latex, exec-path

I have GNU Emacs 27.2 on MacOS 11.6. I have MacTex 2021 installed. I have a simple Latex equation in between $ and $. When I do `C-C C-X C-L` (Latex preview) I get this message:

> Creating LaTeX preview... latex: Command not found. org-compile-file:
> File
> "/var/folders/4y/0rnt489j7yz53_2zwhypf_d00000gn/T/orgtex4qvNUn.dvi"
> wasn’t produced.  Please adjust ‘dvipng’ part of
> ‘org-preview-latex-process-alist’.

latex was installed in /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/universal-darwin and this isn't set up in my path because I'm using the GUI version of emacs.

I have tried to add this directory to exec-path, but it doesn't help.
exec-path is on startup: ("`/usr/bin" "/bin" "/usr/sbin" "/sbin" "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin-x86_64-10_14" "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/libexec-x86_64-10_14" "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/libexec" "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin`")

So I tried to create a symlink in /usr/bin. But that is a read-only file system.
So then I created the symlink in /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin-x86_64-10_14:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 dj    admin      51 Nov 25 16:18 dvipng@ -> /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/universal-darwin/dvipng
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin      50 Nov 25 16:18 latex@ -> /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/universal-darwin/latex
```

But that didn't work either!
How can I get this program into my Emacs path?

Comment: Try the package ```org-fragtog``` available on Melpa - it is designed to solve such problems.

Comment: @Ian: what exactly in `org-fragtog` is designed to solve path problems in macOS? I'm pretty sure this is a false trail for the problem at hand.

Comment: Ok, my bad, I was in a hurry. But looking to your paths configuration, it is not OK; you need to provide a path to divpng executable, which is not found. You can install the package ```exec-path-from-shell```, or add to your configuration this:setenv "PATH" (concat "/Library/TeX/texbin:"
                         (getenv "PATH")))
  (add-to-list 'exec-path "/Library/TeX/texbin").

Comment: Also, on mac it is useful to install ```emacs-plus``` from https://github.com/d12frosted/homebrew-emacs-plus, has some more useful libraries added.

Comment: exec-path-from-shell worked. Many thanks!